# Finding the Fourier Transform of $De^{-\lambda \lvert x\rvert}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm having trouble computing the Fourier transform of the following function:

$$y(x)=De^{-\lambda \lvert x\rvert}$$

It mainly has to do with the integration, I think, but I'll try to attempt it and illustrate where it all goes wrong.

$$\bar f(k) =  \frac{D}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}e^{-\lambda \lvert x \rvert} \ dx$$

$$\bar f(k) =  \frac{D}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx-\lambda \lvert x \rvert} \ dx$$

From here I don't know how to integrate this. I tried a substitution, and quickly realized I couldn't due to the modulus. I was thinking it may be possible to convert the complex exponential into sines and cosines to try and integrate it by parts for each trigonometric component, but I don't think that will be doable since differentiating $e^{-\lambda \lvert x \rvert}$ will not allow for the typical way to integrate an exponential mutipled by a sine or cosine.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{}}=\int_{-\infty }^{0}{{}}+\int_{0}^{\infty }{{}}$ and think about the modulus of x over these ranges.

Comment: Really the same as above, but first show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x){\rm d}x = \int_{0}^\infty [f(x)+f(-x)]{\rm d}x$. With this formulation $|x|$ is not a problem anymore.

Comment: In general dimension, the answer is there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220006/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-exponential-decay-in-mathbbr2/4220125#4220125

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \bar f(k) &\stackrel{(a)}{=}  \frac{D}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}e^{-\lambda \lvert x \rvert} \ dx\\
 &\stackrel{(b)}{=}
 \frac{D}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{ikx}e^{\lambda  x } \ dx
 +
 \frac{D}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ikx}e^{-\lambda  x} \ dx \\
 &\stackrel{(c)}{=}\frac{D}{2\pi}\big( \frac{1}{\lambda + ik}e^{(\lambda+ik)x}\big]_{-\infty}^0 - \frac{1}{-\lambda + ik}e^{(-\lambda+ik)x}\big]^{\infty}_{0} \big)\\
 &\stackrel{(d)}{=}\frac{D}{2\pi}\big( \frac{1}{\lambda + ik} - \frac{1}{-\lambda + ik} \big)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
In $(a)$ we used the definition of Fourier transform.

In $(b)$ we have split the integral and made use of $\vert x \vert = -x$ if $x < 0$ and  $\vert x \vert = x$ if $x \geq 0$.

In $(c)$, we just integrated.

In $(d)$, we replaced the limits.

Comment: How did you evaluate the limits of the $e^{(-\lambda + ik)x}$ integral in (c)?